# Error entering CAPTCHA

Tags: bug, captcha

Why do I keep getting this error when trying to answer a question in one of the Stack Exchange sites? (If this information is relevant, this was my first answer to a question on that site.)

This particular screenshot was taken after my 5th try.

[image: screen shot of error]

This has happened a few times before when I trie to answer a question on one of the SE sites and drives me crazy every time.

More annoyingly, it seems to happen randomly so I can't even recreate it when I want to. That is, sometimes the CAPTCHA works on the first try, and sometimes it doesn't work after multiple tries, even when the entered CAPTCHA was correct every time.

No matter how many times I refresh the CAPTCHA and try again, it's the same thing: CAPTCHA mismatch error when obviously there shouldn't be any.

Why does this happen?

Is it a temporary problem? Because if it is, it happens quite frequently and probably should not be considered temporary.

Or is it a bug in the Stack Exchange software or my browser?

Comment: Are you human?  ;)

Comment: @CC Inc: how do I send it there?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Gort! Klaatu barada nikto!

Comment: I'm having the same problem *right now* on CrossValidated. Tried filling in about 10 CAPTCHAs and also tried listening to the audio (the latter was completely incomprehensible). I'm not using a proxy.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I wasn't even posting something, just using the search. I've altered the user agent on this browser so perhaps that has something to do with it, but for something that started as a technology Q&A it's disappointing to think the devs may be using the user agent string for anything useful 0_O ;-)